# XSL Format issue

Tags: xml, xslt

For some weeks I have been working with XML and XSL. I'm trying to add a stylesheet to my XML, but it hasn't worked for me so far.

I want to add an XSL to this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style2.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<RESPONSE>
    <test>Hello
    </test>
    <MULTIPLE>
        <SINGLE>
            <KEY name="id">
                <VALUE>7
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="shortname">
                <VALUE>Conociendo SAP 
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="fullname">
                <VALUE>Conociendo SAP
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="enrolledusercount">
                <VALUE>1125
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="idnumber">
                <VALUE>012
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="visible">
                <VALUE>1
                </VALUE>
            </KEY>
        </SINGLE>
    </MULTIPLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

And what I have now in my XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
       <xsl:apply-templates /> 
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='RESPONSE'>
<head><title><xsl:value-of select='test' /> (Generado por tienda1-html.xsl)</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1><xsl:value-of select='test' /> </h1>

    <table>
      <tr><th>ID</th><th>Shortname</th><th>Fullname</th></tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I need some orientation about XSL, because it is my first time working on it.

I was trying to get the `<test>` tag first, but it doesn't work. Instead I got a blank page on my web browser.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: 1) You have to be much more clear than "it doesn't work." We cannot read your mind or see your output. What should the output look like and what does it look like?

Comment: Sorry about that,  I just get a blank page in my xampp

Comment: Did you inspect the source of that blank page? Is there any XML at all? Can you check your log files to see what is reported?

Comment: `Premature end of data in tag stylesheet line 2` that chrome says

Comment: In Firefox it does work as expected if you add the closing tag `</xsl:stylesheet>` to the XSLT.

Comment: How did i not see that? thanks for the help, now is working!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the browser is the worst possible place to test your stylesheets. The diagnostics are terrible. It's well worth doing your development and initial testing using a tool like oXygen or Stylus Studio.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I will work with those program then.